# Javascript - BackboneJS - Backbone.sync override - YDN - Asynchronous error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, ydn-db

I'm trying to use YDN with Backbone.sync(), but I've a problem with the « fetchAll » function.

For exemple, I've this View

```
var UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".page",


    initialize: function() {
        this.users = new UserCollection();
    },

    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.users.fetch({
            success:function(users){
                var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users : users.models});
                that.$el.html(template);
            },
            error: function(users){
                console.log("error");
            }
        })      
    }
});
```

And in BackboneSync :

```
switch (method) {
    case "read":
        resp = model.id ? get(model) : all(model);
        break;
    case "create":
        resp = save(model);
        break;
    case "update":
        resp = save(model);
        break;
    case "delete":
        resp = remove(model);
        break;
}

function all(collection) {
    db.values("users", null, 10).done(function(records) {
        $.each(records, function(index, val) {
            collection.add(records);
        });
        return collection;
    });
};
```

I think you know where I'm stuck. `db.values("users", null, 10).done({...});` is an async method, such as `this.users.fetch({})` which, in that case, always return an error.

Do you have an idea on how to handle it ?

Thanks,

Kai23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved :

```
switch (method) {
    case "read":
        model.id ? get(model) : all(model);
        break;
    case "create":
        resp = save(model);
        break;
    case "update":
        resp = save(model);
        break;
    case "delete":
        resp = remove(model);
        break;
}

function all(collection) {
    console.log("je rentre");
    db.values("users", null, 10).done(function(records) {
        options.success(records);            
    });
};
```

And the view :

```
var UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: ".page",


initialize: function() {
    this.users = new UserCollection();
},

render: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.users.fetch({
        success:function(users){
            console.log(users.models);
            var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users : users.models});
            that.$el.html(template);
        }
    })      
}
});
```